# How to fix "Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set' in..."

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to create a web scraper that retrieves multiple tables from a website, but somehow I can't extract them

I've searched for a solution but nothing seems to fit my needs :(

```py
def parse(self, response):
        tables=[]
        for table in response.xpath('//table'):
            yield {
                tables.append(self.retrieve_table(table))
            }

        tables[0] = self.extract_table_info(tables[0] + tables[1])
        tables[2] = self.extract_table_info(tables[2], 1)
        tables[3] = self.extract_table_info(tables[3], 2)
        tables[4] = self.extract_table_info(tables[4], 3)

        company = { 'info': tables[0],
                    'oscilations': tables[2]['oscilations'],
                    'fundamentals': tables[2]['fundamentals'],
                    'patrimonial_balance_data': tables[3],
                    'demonstrative_results_data': tables[4] }

        import json
        with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(company, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

The error that it's returning is

```
ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'set'
```

Comment: somehwere some of your parse methods returns a set object. Could you post full spider code or full `parse()` method?

Comment: You are yielding a set at the top of your method. Should that be a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of this block:

```
for table in response.xpath('//table'):
    yield {
        tables.append(self.retrieve_table(table))
    }
```

Why do you need `yield` here? It seems that just appending will be enough for your goals:

```
for table in response.xpath('//table'):
    tables.append(self.retrieve_table(table))
```

Or even just:

```
tables = response.xpath('//table')
```

Comment: Worked completely fine! Thanks